# no such file to load -- openssl ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I did this steps : http://blog.overridethis.com/blog/post/2011/04/19/Installing-Rails-305-on-Ubuntu-1010-(Maverick).aspx

Then I have this error message. I read many topics but I couldn't fix my problem with any of them..

Comment: You will find better support for this on http://askubuntu.com/ or http://serverfault.com/.

Comment: better try installing from the official rails site.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't `apt-get install openssl` before hand. You'll need to install that package before re-compiling Ruby to get it to work.

If you were using RVM (and you should!) then this whole process would be a lot easier!

I warn about the dangers of installing Ruby from `apt-get`  and explain [how to install Ruby properly with RVM](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/) in this post.

Comment: Could you tell me should I uninstall something or I can start doing tips in your link?

Comment: Start doing the tips in my link. Don't use apt-get to install Ruby, EVER.